# Apply conditional operation to each element of a vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, rounding

I have a vector such `V = [0.5,0.6,0.2,0.8...]` and I want to map each element to its nearest integer 0 or 1.

What is the function or method to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`round()` is doing that :) is it obvious, silly me !